# How can I reach a nested element in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array like this:

```
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes) 

[{…}]
0:
field: Array(8)
0: "Wood"
1: "Grain"
2: "Grain"
3: "Grain"
4: "Stone"
5: "Iron"
6: "Grain"
7: "Grain"
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
id: "-MHLWLm8bFRE2_1aahWk"
userId: "lPqZ8Oj90Se2qBEIzTJq1OSfbo62"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

now i want to reach e.g. the first item "Wood"

i tried

```
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes[0])
```

that gave me:

```
{field: Array(8), userId: "lPqZ8Oj90Se2qBEIzTJq1OSfbo62", id: "-MHLWLm8bFRE2_1aahWk"}
field: Array(8)
0: "Wood"
1: "Grain"
2: "Grain"
3: "Grain"
4: "Stone"
5: "Iron"
6: "Grain"
7: "Grain"
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
id: "-MHLWLm8bFRE2_1aahWk"
userId: "lPqZ8Oj90Se2qBEIzTJq1OSfbo62"
__proto__: Object
```

but i cant get the deeper nested item. I tried

console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes[0].field) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes[0][0]) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes[0].field[0]) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes.field) // undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tevemadar/xd5c0m2t/ produces the same output for the first two attempt as you describe, and the last two attempts are working as expected (open the actual JS console of the browser). If your data behaves differently, an important detail would be: where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
console.log(this.props.countrysideTypes[0].field[0])
```

You have an array with Object in it. In the Object you have the array yu would like to access and it is assigned to property field.

Comment: yes, thats what i assumed as well, but it doesn't. this gives me:  Cannot read property 'field' of undefined

Comment: this is the way to access nested object in array, check for typo errors and log the props to check if you receive everyrhing you want to access

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your kind help! The data comes from firebase realtime Database. It seems it was just nested too deeply.
Finally it worked like so:

```
    let objectArray = Object.entries(this.props.countrysideTypes);

    let types = [];

    objectArray.forEach(([key, value]) => {
        types = value.field;
      });

    console.log(types[0]); //"Wood"
```